# Periodic absolute value function

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, absolute-value, periodic-functions

Define

$$h(x)=|x|$$

on the interval $[-1,1]$ and extend the defintion of $h$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by requiring that $h(x+2)=h(x)$.

Now define the function:

$$h_n (x)=\frac{1}{2^n} h(2^n x)$$

Could you please help me understand why the maximum height of the latter function is $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and the period is $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$?

My confusion arises from the fact that I see no reason why the $2^n$ cannot be cancelled based on the definition of $h$. We are left with the original function in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: the maximum of h(x) is 1.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Obviously. I am asking about the function $h_n (x)$

Comment: $h_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}h(t)$ See now?

Comment: @Sabyasachi I'm quite stuck, no :\

Comment: In $h_n(x)$ substitute $t=2^nx$. therefore $h_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}h(t)$. As you said, maximum of $h$ is 1. therefore maximum of $h_n(x)$ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: Oh right, I see it now. You can post your comments as full answer and I will mark it the right one if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of $h(x)$ is $1$.

We have $h_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}h(t)$, where $t=2^nx$

As we have maximum of $h$ as 1.

$$h(t)\le1$$
$$h_n(x)=\frac1{2^n}h(t)\le\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: Hey sorry, would you mind also explaining the statement: "for $0 \leq n \leq k <m$ , and $x=\frac{p}{2^k}$,$p \in \mathbb{Z}$ $2^n x$ and $2^{n-m}$ fall on the same linear segment of $h(x)$?

Comment: @JohnK linear segment would mean "branch" of the $|x|$ function. can you see it. It just means that $2^n \le 2^k \lt 2^m$

Comment: That was fast, thanks. But what about the case when $x<0$? It falls on a different branch.

Comment: @JohnK the condition $0\le n$ is stated, so it doesn't matter here.

Comment: $p$ and therefore $x$ can still be negative though, no?

Comment: okay I didn't see your edited comment, yes it can. I think there is a typo though. It should be $2^{n-m}\color{red}{x}$. Would that clear up your doubt?

Comment: Book's typo, very badly written at this Chapter. They won't still fall on different branches if $x$ is negative?

Comment: @JohnK no. because then *both* $2^n x$ and $2^{n-m} x$ would be negative. To understand why that helps, you need to see that $h$ is even and symetrical about the y axis.

Comment: Oh right, you meant replace $2^{n-m}$ with $2^{n-m} x$, not the other term. This is taken from Understanding Analysis by Abbott, by the way. I'm glad you were around to clear things a bit. Enjoy your weekend dude.

Comment: @JohnK Thanks. same to you. I have exams going on though.

Comment: No worries. Good luck!